# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND - when connecting to mysql database with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I wanna connect to my database. Im using a node.js server with a mysql database. Localhost works, but when I try to connect to my database I get this error:

```
listening on *:80
/var/www/vhosts/hosting154497.a2e9d.netcup.net/httpdocs/app.js:17
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND artisgralb643.mysql.db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/vhosts/hosting154497.a2e9d.netcup.net/httpdocs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/vhosts/hosting154497.a2e9d.netcup.net/httpdocs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/vhosts/hosting154497.a2e9d.netcup.net/httpdocs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/hosting154497.a2e9d.netcup.net/httpdocs/app.js:16:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'artisgralb643.mysql.db',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Either you're giving the wrong hostname or the name isn't in DNS correctly.

Comment: `artisgalb643.mysql.db` doesn't seem like a valid hostname. That looks like a database name.